# ActionScript 3 subclass' method inheritance issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, inheritance, casting

I have a class Goo like this:

```
public class Goo extends Node
{
    public function Update(dt:Number):void
    {
        // function to be overriden
        trace("updating Goo");
    }
}
```

and a subclass of Goo called GooX:

```
public class GooX extends Goo
{
    override public function Update(dt:Number):void
    {
        trace("updating GooX");
    }
}
```

and another called GooY:

```
public class GooY extends Goo
{
    override public function Update(dt:Number):void
    {
        trace("updating GooY");
    }
}
```

and then a Manager which creates Goo objects and updates them like this:

```
public class Manager
{
    private var gooArray:Vector.<Goo> = new Vector.<Goo>();

    public function Manager():void
    {
        var aGoo:Goo;
        if (Math.random() >= 0.5)
        {
            aGoo = new GooX();
        }
        else
        {
            aGoo = new GooY();
        }
        gooArray.push(aGoo);
    }

    public function Update(dt:Number):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < gooArray.length; i++)
        {
            gooArray[i].Update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

this code always shows "updating Goo" in the trace log.  I tried also detecting which type is it by doing a `gooArray[i] is GooX` or `gooArray[i] is GooY` but it's always `false` for both.  Even if I force a cast with `gooArray[i] as GooX` it will *always* say that the object is `null`.

Does anybody knows a way to do what I'm trying to do (let the Update of the child class being called instead of the one of the parent class)?  Thanks.

Comment: I just put in the code you posted here almost verbatim and I don't get the same results as you. The overridden method gets called for me, so I think you have something else going on.

Comment: Classes work just fine for me.  Flash Player 11.0.1.152 compiled in FlashBuilder with Flex 4.1 SDK.  Output I get is "updating GooX".  If I plug it into an ENTER_FRAME loop, I get a fairly even dispersal between GooX and GooY.

Comment: That's weird, I'm running it using Flash Builder 4.6 with Flex SDK 4.1 and Flash Player 11.  It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You're example is logically correct to Actionscript3, but your confusion might be caused on the manager's constructor since it makes a random object of either type. To better test the problem, replace the manager's constructor with:

```
public function Manager():void
{
    gooArray.push(new GooY());
    gooArray.push(new GooX());
}
```

This problem might be an odd bug in the compiler that you are using. Try upgrading to the latest SDK, do a clean project, and see if you still get the same issue.

Lastly, what is this "Node" object? Perhaps, as a highly improbable idea, that Node is some kind of Object Proxy that is hijacking method calls. However, I doubt this applies to your project.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the example is logically correct and is working right on its own.  I think I might have found the problem.  Of course the example code belongs to a wider project and I was abstracting the relevant part in case I was missing something (I'm not expert in AS3).  The problem was that someone was cloning the subclassed Goo object and making it a Goo object again.  Maybe a reason why abstract classes are so important?